# Pattern matching field names with jq

Tags: json, regex, key, match, jq

This is a very basic (probably silly) question but I can't get it to work...

I have a JSON file with this structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "what a burger": [1,2,3],
        "wap": [66],
        "the map": [11,20],
        "H. Incandenza": [1,1],
        "What a burger": [a,a,3]
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the values of the fields within *data* whose "name" matches a certain pattern. For example, I would like to extract all the case-insensitive coincidences of "what a burger" to get

```
[1,2,3],[a,a,3]
```

My guess would be something like

```
jq '.data | match("what a burger";"i")'
```

but this results in

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:9): object ({"what a bu...) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your statement does not work, because you try to feed the data object into match, but match can only work on strings.

The following expression will do what you want. The `to_entries` converts the object to an array of keys and values. Then we iterate over this array by using `map` and `select` all entries where the `.key` (now a string) has a `match`. Finally we just print out the value of every element.

```
.data | to_entries | map(select(.key | match("what a burger";"i"))) | map(.value)
```

However, two comments:

- The `[a,a,3]` is not allowed in JSON, because `a` is not a number.
- It works because the keys ARE actually different, even if only the letter case is not equal. If at least two keys are identical, you will run into problems, because keys should be unique. In fact, `jq` will only output one of the elements then.

Comment: The two `map` calls can and should be combined.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a slightly briefer alternative:

```
.data | with_entries(select(.key|match("what a burger";"i")))[]
```

After rectifying the input, and using jq's -c option, this would produce the two lines:

```
[1,2,3]
["a","a",3]
```

Comment: I like this one, and helped me figure out to get all key:values if the key contains a patern (or is uniq)

For all values where key name is "keynameSOMETHING"
`.data | with_entries(select(.key|match("keyname+";"ig")))[]`

For key:value with the same filer we just remove the [] at the end... and even works if I want to search more than one PATTERN in the keyname like:

`.data | with_entries(select(.key|match("contains1+", "contains2+"; "ig")))`

couldn't done it without you're suggestion though @peak so thank